# Unable to install React Native cli on Mac using npm

Tags: macos, react-native, npm, terminal, react-native-ios

Unable to install React Native cli on Mac using npm!

I have tried uninstalling both node and npm and trying the command `npm install -g react-native-cli`.

Also tried this,

> "If you get an error like Cannot find module 'npmlog', try installing npm directly: `curl -0 -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`"

[image: screenshot of the errors in the terminal]

Comment: try to use yarn instead of npm !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

Also, you can use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)!

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept and vote up an answer for further references.